# Replacing Individual Entries in Fixed Width File

Tags: bash, sed, echo, cut

I have a fixed-width data file that looks like this:

```
ATOM   6181  H4  BGLC    2      -6.078 -11.556   0.599  1.00  0.00
ATOM   6182  O4  BGLC    2      -5.410 -10.816   2.307  1.00  7.76
ATOM   6183  C6  BGLC    2      -8.313 -11.233   1.955  1.00  8.41
ATOM   6184  H61 BGLC    2      -9.308 -11.734   2.225  1.00  0.00
ATOM   6185  H62 BGLC    2      -8.302 -10.340   2.573  1.00  0.00
ATOM   6186  O6  BGLC    2      -8.412 -11.033   0.547  1.00  8.44
ATOM   6187  HO6 BGLC    2      -7.623 -10.829   0.055  1.00  0.00
ATOM   6188  C1  BGLC    3      -4.821  -9.797   1.481  1.00  7.45
ATOM   6189  H1  BGLC    3      -5.419  -9.613   0.596  1.00  0.00
```

I am trying to replace the last two columns with other variables `charge` and `radius`. I've tried using cut to pick out the first 54 characters of the line (the first 8 columns) and then using echo to tack `charge` and `radius` onto the end, like this:

```
newline=$(echo $(echo $pqratomline | cut -c 1-54) $charge $radius)
```

where `pqratomline` is a string equal to a particular line in the file. However, echo strips out the extra whitespace, which throws off the fixed width columns.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to do this without using echo, or to keep echo from removing that extra whitespace?

**EDIT:**
I'd like to get something that looks like this (just showing the first few lines):

```
ATOM   6181  H4  BGLC    2      -6.078 -11.556   0.599  0.0900  1.3400
ATOM   6182  O4  BGLC    2      -5.410 -10.816   2.307 -0.6500  1.7650
```

Instead, I'm getting:

```
ATOM 6181 H4 BGLC 2 -6.078 -11.556 0.599 0.0900 1.3400
ATOM 6182 O4 BGLC 2 -5.410 -10.816 2.307 -0.6500 1.7650
```

Comment: ok, show the final result to get a quick help

Comment: Per @RomanPerekhrest's comment on my question below, are you comfortable with charge and radius falling within a range of -99.9999 to 999.9999?  That's the limit of `%8.4f`, the format you appear to be using for these numbers in your sample output.

Comment: @ghoti yes, those limits are fine. Charge is confined by [-1.0000,1.0000]. Radius doesn't technically have an upper limit, but it should fall somewhere in the range (0.0000, 4.0000(ish)].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative you can use `printf` instead of `echo` since `printf` has much better behavior and you can also adjust the width of each printed variable:

```
$ echo "$a"
ATOM   6179  HO3 BGLC    2      -3.020 -13.471   0.981  1.00  0.00

$ charge="2.22";radius="2.22"

$ newline=$(printf '%s%6s%6s\n' "$(echo "$a" | cut -c 1-54)" "$charge" "$radius");echo "$newline"
ATOM   6179  HO3 BGLC    2      -3.020 -13.471   0.981  2.22  2.22
```

The `%6s` format in `printf` dictates variable to be printed with 6 chars width.

Similarly:

```
$ echo "$a"
ATOM   6179  HO3 BGLC    2      -3.020 -13.471   0.981  1.00  0.00

$ charge="0.0900";radius="1.3400"

$ newline=$(printf '%s%12s%12s\n' "$(echo "$a" | cut -c 1-54)" "$charge" "$radius");echo "$newline"
ATOM   6179  HO3 BGLC    2      -3.020 -13.471   0.981      0.0900      1.3400
```

You can adjust the value of the new fields width (`%12s` above) according to your needs.

Comment: +1 for recommending printf, but -1 for suggesting a solution that trashes the OP's fixed-width formatting in its output.  +0!  :-D

Comment: I agree that `sub()` on `$0` is a great way to avoid breaking fixed-width formatting ... except that `charge=1.25` will yield a different column width than `charge=123.45`. You need to control formatting on ALL columns. Perhaps you can use `sprintf()`.

Comment: @ghoti The use of sub tends to be problematic in my tests with charge=0.0900 and radius=1.3400. I will remove all awk code and i will keep only the printf advise. Better to remove also the comments inhere to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions! I wound up using this idea, it worked well with my fixed spacing once I forced my variables to have 6 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your charge and radius variables don't contain backreferences or /s or anything else sed might care about:

```
$ charge=7
$ radius=2.5

$ sed 's/[^ ]*\( *\)[^ ]*$/'"$charge"'\1'"$radius"'/' file
ATOM   6181  H4  BGLC    2      -6.078 -11.556   0.599  7  2.5
ATOM   6182  O4  BGLC    2      -5.410 -10.816   2.307  7  2.5
```

Note that your posted expected output does not follow the same fixed width layout as your input (it retains spacing between the last 2 fields but expands the space occupied by the each of them) so neither does the above solution.

Answer (score -1):

One problem with awk is that unless you take special care to do prepare your output format, it'll remove whitespace, thus trashing your fix-width spacing.

```
awk -v charge="$charge" -v radius="$radius" '
  {
    printf "%54s%8.4f%8.4f\n", substr($0,1,54), charge, radius
  }
' input.txt
```

This uses awk's `-v` option to insert an environment variable into the awk script.

Of course, you could just do this in bash and use parameter expansion to strip the portions of the line you don't want...

```
while read line; do

  lhs=${line:0:54}    # The first 54 characters...
  rhs=${line:54}      # in case you need these for later...

  printf '%s%8.4f%8.4f\n' "$lhs" "$charge" "$radius"

done < input.txt
```

Comment: Ah, love those downvotes-without-comments. Can anyone see anything wrong with my answer? I'd love the opportunity to fix it.

Comment: but why `8.4f`? what if the numbers would be as `11234.0055  22234.0055`? does it retain fix-width spacing in such case?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - the OP's "goal" output contained an 8-character fixed-length field with 4 decimal places. `__0.0900`, `_-0.6500`, etc. If the charge and radius were over 999, the OP would need to adjust his file format.